# Boot Loader doesn't offer windows 7?

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I have two HDD one has windows 7 and I installed ubuntu on second HDD when I reboot there is no windows 7 option?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the Ubuntu installer didn't recognize Windows or didn't include Windows because it wasn't on that drive. Try running `sudo grub-probe`, marking down what it said, and trying a reboot.